# Open() syscall on linux freezes terminal

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, linux-device-driver, system-calls, tty

Im trying to make a connection to a rs232 serial card PCIe-1622. I've compiled the drivers and installed the kernel modules (adv_17v35x). And in /dev it shows the relevant tty devices.

However, when I go to test them by `echo`ing data to them or with `cat`. It freezes, and I get left with a cursor on the next line with no output. I can Ctrl-c to exit.

After some looking around online, I've made a simple program that opens the dev file, using `open("/dev/ttyB15P0", O_RDWR);` but the program gets stuck on that line, same symptoms as with echo/cat. I've placed an `fprintf(stderr,"test");` before and after it, so I know it is that line/function that's holding up the program.

Does anyone have any info or insight as to what might be causing this issue, why is the device file failing to open, or even return a null file descriptor or error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Study the **man** page for the **open()** syscall and the O_NONBLOCK option.  Once opened, use **fcntl()** to restore blocking mode.

Comment: Run `sudo stty -aF /dev/ttyB15P0` and look for `clocal` or `-clocal`. If it says `-clocal` then a blocking `open` call will block waiting for the DCD (carrier detect) modem control signal to be asserted. If it says `clocal` then DCD  will be ignored. The `stty` command can be used to alter the settings, e.g. `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyB15P0 clocal` will turn on the option to ignore DCD. The adv_17v35x driver might be initializing its termios settings differently to the standard serial drivers.

Comment: Thank you, that has helped clear the problem, echo now terminates and the shell resumes. However, it's I don't think it's working correctly.  I have one channel of the card p7, plugged back into another p6, for testing. My thought was that if it's working correctly I could ```tail -f p6``` in one terminal, and echo to p7 in another and it should go though, out of the machine along the wire then back in. However, all I get is a blank screen on tail. Any thoughts. Again thanks for the previous comment.